# How to follow packets of a specific email when a lot of mail is recieved at the same time?

Tags: email, smtp, wireshark

The smtp protocol is basically like this:

```
S: 220 smtp.example.com ESMTP Postfix
C: HELO relay.example.org
S: 250 Hello relay.example.org, I am glad to meet you
C: MAIL FROM:<bob@example.org>
S: 250 Ok
C: RCPT TO:<alice@example.com>
S: 250 Ok
C: RCPT TO:<theboss@example.com>
S: 250 Ok
C: DATA
S: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
C: From: "Bob Example" <bob@example.org>
C: To: "Alice Example" <alice@example.com>
C: Cc: theboss@example.com
C: Date: Tue, 15 Jan 2008 16:02:43 -0500
C: Subject: Test message
C:
C: Hello Alice.
C: This is a test message with 5 header fields and 4 lines in the message body.
C: Your friend,
C: Bob
C: .
S: 250 Ok: queued as 12345
C: QUIT
S: 221 Bye
```

But when multiple mails are recieved it becomes more complicated

```
S: 220 smtp.example.com ESMTP Postfix
C: HELO relay.example.org
C: HELO relay.example.org
S: 250 Hello relay.example.org, I am glad to meet you
C: MAIL FROM:<bob@example.org>
S: 250 Ok
C: RCPT TO:<alice@example.com>
**C2: MAIL FROM:<charliebitme@example.org>**
S: 250 Ok
**C2: RCPT TO:<ouch@example.org>**
C: RCPT TO:<theboss@example.com>
S: 250 Ok
C: DATA
**C2: DATA2
C3: MAIL FROM:<foo@example.org>
C3: RCPT TO:<bar@example.com>**
S: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
**C3: DATA3**
C: From: "Bob Example" <bob@example.org>
C: To: "Alice Example" <alice@example.com>
C: Cc: theboss@example.com
C: Date: Tue, 15 Jan 2008 16:02:43 -0500
C: Subject: Test message
C:
C: Hello Alice.
C: This is a test message with 5 header fields and 4 lines in the message body.
C: Your friend,
C: Bob
C: .
S: 250 Ok: queued as 12345
C: QUIT
S: 221 Bye
```

So how can I determine which data packet belongs to C , C1 , C2. Or who is sending mail to ouch@example.org using wireshark?

Answer (score 1):

Try to create TCP (tcp.port, tcp.srcport or tcp.dstport) or IP (ip.addr, ip.src or ip.dst) filter. Using this kind of filters you should be able to extract only one connection.

Comment: But I want to log these entries. So for example 1.2.3.4 ip sent mail from x@y.com to a@b.com. 2.3.4.5 ip sent mail from aa@bb.com to cc@dd.com. So I can't apply an ip filter as I want to capture all ip addresses. And of course I am using port filters to display only smtp traffic

Comment: You should capture everything but after this when you want to analyze your capture just create some temporary filer rules to distinguish each SMTP connection. For your examples this could be something like this: "smtp && ip.addr == 1.2.3.4" and second filetr : "smtp && ip.addr == 2.3.4.5"